# Array.reduce and recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to nest a recursive function in an `Array.reduce` call.

But the following does not work for the third instance only

```
const i1 = {'local': [['a','b']]};
const i2 = {'local': [['c','d']], 'recursive': []};
const i3 = {'local': [['c','d']], 'recursive': [{'local': [['e','f']]}]};

function reduce(current, result = []) {

    if(current.hasOwnProperty('local'))
       result.push(...current.local);

    if(current.hasOwnProperty('recursive'))
       result = current.recursive.reduce(reduce, result);
    //'result =' should be optional, but yields a wrong answer anyway

    return result;    
}

console.log(reduce(i1));
console.log(reduce(i2));
console.log(reduce(i3));
```

So instead of calling `reduce` I tried the following loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < current.recursive.length; ++i)
    result = reduce(current.recursive[i], result);
 //'result = ' is optional for it is passed by reference
```

and it works.
Being new to JavaScript, I am certain of missing a key feature here, so could you explain ?

Output for the third instance should be

```
[ [ 'c', 'd' ], [ 'e', 'f' ] ]
```

but is

```
{ local: [ [ 'e', 'f' ] ] }
```

or

```
[ [ 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

when `result =` is removed.

Comment: why do you use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)? why do you need a recursion? the data base is not the same and the signature of `Array#reduce` needs the second parameter for the element.

Comment: You've made your code extra confusing by combining manual recursion with `Array#reduce`, mixing assignments and functional style, and naming your own function `reduce`. But I think the main issue is that your order of arguments is wrong. It should be `function reduce(result, current)`.

Comment: The callback to array `reduce` takes the accumulator first and the element second.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have checked the doc again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of the parameters, the first argument to the reduce callback function is the accumulator not the current value. Try this:

```js
const i1 = {'local': [['a','b']]};
const i2 = {'local': [['c','d']], 'recursive': []};
const i3 = {'local': [['c','d']], 'recursive': [{'local': [['e','f']]}]};

function reduce(result, current) {

    if(current.hasOwnProperty('local'))
       result.push(...current.local);

    if(current.hasOwnProperty('recursive'))
       result = current.recursive.reduce(reduce, result);
    //'result =' should be optional, but yields a wrong answer anyway

    return result;    
}

console.log(reduce([], i1));
console.log(reduce([], i2));
console.log(reduce([], i3));
```

Comment: You could also make the first argument optional, allowing you to simply call `reduce(i1)`. Add `if (current === undefined) { current = result; result = []; }` to the start of the `reduce` function.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm sure the OP will change this to fit his needs, I just wanted show what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This only covers the cases when `local` and `recursive` only includes one element, like in your example.

```js
const i1 = { local: [["a", "b"]] };
const i2 = { local: [["c", "d"]], recursive: [] };
const i3 = { local: [["c", "d"]], recursive: [{ local: [["e", "f"]] }] };
const i4 = {
  local: [["c", "d"]],
  recursive: [{ local: [["e", "f"]], recursive: [{ local: [["g", "h"]] }] }]
};

const solution = ({ local: [firstItem], recursive }) =>
  [firstItem].concat(
    recursive && recursive.length ? solution(recursive[0]) : []
  );

console.log(solution(i1));
console.log(solution(i2));
console.log(solution(i3));
console.log(solution(i4));
```

Comment: `local` and `recursive` are arrays so it makes sense to me to append all children, not just the first, `firstItem` and `recursive[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to implement is `flatten` - It's no coincidence that it's a simple wrapper for `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```js
const i1 =
  { local: [[1,2]] }

const i2 = 
  { local: [[3,4]], recursive: [] }

const i3 =
  { local: [[3,4]], recursive: [{ local: [[5,6]] }] }

const i4 =
  { local: [[1,2]],
    recursive: [
      { local: [[3,4]] },
      { local: [[5,6]] , recursive: [{ local: [[7,8]] }] }] }

const flatten = ({ local = [], recursive = [] }) =>
  [ ...local, ...recursive.flatMap(flatten) ]

console.log(flatten(i1))
// [ [ 1, 2 ] ]

console.log(flatten(i2))
// [ [ 3, 4 ] ]

console.log(flatten(i3))
// [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]

console.log(flatten(i4))
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ] ]
```

The spread arguments can be traded for `Array.prototype.concat`, if that is preferred -

```js
const flatten = ({ local = [], recursive = [] }) =>
  [ ...local, ...recursive.flatMap(flatten) ]
  local.concat(recursive.flatMap(flatten))
```

---

`Array.prototype.flatMap` is a special kind of `Array.prototype.reduce` -

```
const flatten = ({ local = [], recursive = [] }) =>
  local.concat(
    recursive.reduce((r, x) => r.concat(flatten(x)), [])
  )
```

And since `Array.prototype.concat` is a pure operation, we can simplify it a bit more -

```
const flatten = ({ local = [], recursive = [] }) =>
  recursive.reduce((r, x) => r.concat(flatten(x)), local)
```

And finally we see it again using `reduce` and array spread arguments -

```
const flatten = ({ local = [], recursive = [] }) =>
  recursive.reduce((r, x) => [...r, ...flatten(x)], local)
```

Each of these `flatten` produce the exact same outputs and the input arrays are not mutated in the process. Hopefully this gives you a little insight on how the helpful `Array.prototype.flatMap` works.